# Profile on PulseAudio not properly setting or working

Tags: linux, audio, pulseaudio, alsa, void-linux

I recently switched over to Linux and on any distro I try, I can't get PulseAudio to set the proper profile. In my `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/profile-sets/default.conf` file, this is what I have as a custom profile:

```
[Profile output:analog-stereo+output:iec958-stereo]
description = Astro Mixamp Pro Audio
output-mappings = analog-stereo iec958-stereo
```

And to add to that, when I try setting my default profile, pulse audio refuses to start with the error, `E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.` This is what I have inside of `/etc/pulse/default.pa:`

```
set-card-profile alsa_card.usb-Astro_Gaming_Astro_MixAmp_Pro-00 output:analog-stereo+output:iec958-stereo
```

And the output of `pacmd list-cards:`

```
index: 0
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 6
    properties:
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA ATI HDMI"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA ATI HDMI at 0xfea60000 irq 42"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:00.1"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "1002"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]"
        device.product.id = "aae0"
        device.product.name = "Baffin HDMI/DP Audio [Radeon RX 550 640SP / RX 560/560X]"
        device.string = "1"
        device.description = "Baffin HDMI/DP Audio [Radeon RX 550 640SP / RX 560/560X]"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5900, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (priority 5700, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra3: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra3: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra3: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra4: Digital Stereo (HDMI 5) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra4: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra4: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <output:hdmi-stereo-extra2>
    sinks:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra2/#0: Baffin HDMI/DP Audio [Radeon RX 550 640SP / RX 560/560X] Digital Stereo (HDMI 3)
    sources:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo-extra2.monitor/#0: Monitor of Baffin HDMI/DP Audio [Radeon RX 550 640SP / RX 560/560X] Digital Stereo (HDMI 3)
    ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                device.product.name = "Sceptre L24"
        hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (priority 5600, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-4: HDMI / DisplayPort 5 (priority 5500, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
index: 1
    name: <alsa_card.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._USB_Advanced_Audio_Device-00>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.card = "2"
        alsa.card_name = "USB Advanced Audio Device"
        alsa.long_card_name = "C-Media Electronics Inc. USB Advanced Audio Device at usb-0000:00:12.0-2, full"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:12.0-usb-0:2:1.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb6/6-2/6-2:1.0/sound/card2"
        udev.id = "usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._USB_Advanced_Audio_Device-00"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.vendor.id = "0d8c"
        device.vendor.name = "C-Media Electronics, Inc."
        device.product.id = "016c"
        device.product.name = "USB Advanced Audio Device"
        device.serial = "C-Media_Electronics_Inc._USB_Advanced_Audio_Device"
        device.string = "2"
        device.description = "USB Advanced Audio Device"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-usb"
    profiles:
        input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (priority 65, available: unknown)
        input:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Input (priority 55, available: unknown)
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (priority 6500, available: unknown)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (priority 6565, available: unknown)
        output:analog-stereo+input:iec958-stereo: Analog Stereo Output + Digital Stereo (IEC958) Input (priority 6555, available: unknown)
        output:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output (priority 5500, available: unknown)
        output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 5565, available: unknown)
        output:iec958-stereo+input:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo Duplex (IEC958) (priority 5555, available: unknown)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo>
    sinks:
        alsa_output.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._USB_Advanced_Audio_Device-00.analog-stereo/#1: USB Advanced Audio Device Analog Stereo
    sources:
        alsa_output.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._USB_Advanced_Audio_Device-00.analog-stereo.monitor/#1: Monitor of USB Advanced Audio Device Analog Stereo
        alsa_input.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._USB_Advanced_Audio_Device-00.analog-stereo/#2: USB Advanced Audio Device Analog Stereo
    ports:
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        iec958-stereo-input: Digital Input (S/PDIF) (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
        iec958-stereo-output: Digital Output (S/PDIF) (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                
index: 2
    name: <alsa_card.usb-Astro_Gaming_Astro_MixAmp_Pro-00>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 8
    properties:
        alsa.card = "3"
        alsa.card_name = "Astro MixAmp Pro"
        alsa.long_card_name = "Astro Gaming Astro MixAmp Pro at usb-0000:00:12.2-1, high speed"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:12.2-usb-0:1:1.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/sound/card3"
        udev.id = "usb-Astro_Gaming_Astro_MixAmp_Pro-00"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.vendor.id = "9886"
        device.vendor.name = "Astro Gaming"
        device.product.id = "0018"
        device.product.name = "Astro MixAmp Pro"
        device.serial = "Astro_Gaming_Astro_MixAmp_Pro"
        device.string = "3"
        device.description = "Astro MixAmp Pro"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-usb"
    profiles:
        input:mono-fallback: Mono Input (priority 1, available: unknown)
        input:multichannel-input: Multichannel Input (priority 1, available: unknown)
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (priority 6500, available: unknown)
        output:analog-stereo+input:mono-fallback: Analog Stereo Output + Mono Input (priority 6501, available: unknown)
        output:analog-stereo+input:multichannel-input: Analog Stereo Output + Multichannel Input (priority 6501, available: unknown)
        output:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output (priority 5500, available: unknown)
        output:iec958-stereo+input:mono-fallback: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output + Mono Input (priority 5501, available: unknown)
        output:iec958-stereo+input:multichannel-input: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output + Multichannel Input (priority 5501, available: unknown)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <output:analog-stereo+input:mono-fallback>
    sinks:
        alsa_output.usb-Astro_Gaming_Astro_MixAmp_Pro-00.analog-stereo/#2: Astro MixAmp Pro Analog Stereo
    sources:
        alsa_output.usb-Astro_Gaming_Astro_MixAmp_Pro-00.analog-stereo.monitor/#3: Monitor of Astro MixAmp Pro Analog Stereo
        alsa_input.usb-Astro_Gaming_Astro_MixAmp_Pro-00.mono-fallback/#4: Astro MixAmp Pro Mono
    ports:
        analog-input: Analog Input (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                
        multichannel-input: Multichannel Input (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                
        analog-output: Analog Output (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                
        iec958-stereo-output: Digital Output (S/PDIF) (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                
index: 3
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_14.2>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 9
    properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xfeb00000 irq 16"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.2"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.2/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "1022"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]"
        device.product.id = "780d"
        device.product.name = "FCH Azalia Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        output:analog-stereo+output:iec958-stereo: Astro Mixamp Pro Audio (priority 0, available: unknown)
        input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (priority 65, available: no)
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (priority 6500, available: no)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (priority 6565, available: no)
        output:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output (priority 5500, available: unknown)
        output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 5565, available: no)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <output:iec958-stereo>
    sinks:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_14.2.iec958-stereo/#3: Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (IEC958)
    sources:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_14.2.iec958-stereo.monitor/#5: Monitor of Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (IEC958)
    ports:
        analog-output-lineout: Line Out (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
        iec958-stereo-output: Digital Output (S/PDIF) (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                
        analog-input-front-mic: Front Microphone (priority 8500, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-input-rear-mic: Rear Microphone (priority 8200, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-input-linein: Line In (priority 8100, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.